# 2010 Chevy Traverse Driver window controller

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, power-windows, traverse

One of the buttons on the driver side window controller failed.  All the other buttons work fine ( other three windows, mirror controls, etc ).

I purchases the exact part from Amazon, and I mean the exact part number is on both old and new part.  Its very easy to remove the old controller ( which has all buttons on it, you cannot just replace one ) and install the new one.

When I replace the controller, none of the buttons would light up or work.  At this point I thought I got a DOA unit and exchanged it.  When I tried the second part, it still would not light up or work which lead me to think there must be some sort of programming you have to do that of course is not in the owners manual.

Does anyone know how to program the part?  I assumed that since it was the exact model it would work, but of course it does't.

The part is made by BOSCH and the part number is ACDelco D1437H

Comment: Shouldn't need to be programmed. Check that all connections are made properly. Sometimes when the connectors come loose they fall into the door. Maybe, they are not all connected. After that, check fuses.

Comment: Is this with or without express up/down functions? At most you have to relearn the window position for express up/down. check for power and ground at the connector

Comment: With express up/down on front only

Comment: You can easily check to ensure there is continuity through the pins on the switch, as well as for power at the connections. STUPID QUESTION ALERT: Was the key on when you tested it?

Comment: Yes the key was on. I'm also sure the continuity is fine as if I hook up the old controller everything but that one stupid switch works fine

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 is talking about continuity in the switch it self. The way the express master switch works it's not possible without removing the board from the housing. Another thing you may want to check for is bent pins in the new master switch. If the pins in the switch look OK plug in the connector and take a small pin and push on each of the connector terminals. The express switch uses the serial data line to communicate with each door module and in turn each module controls the motor. as long as you have good B+ and ground the switch should illuminate barring a defective part.